# oracle query to display the similar value rows at last..?

Tags: oracle, customization

I need to display the similar values rows of the table at last while the remaining rows of the table has to come in ascending order...

for ex:

```
Name         salary
---------------------
a             100
b             200
c             300
c             400
c             600
d             200
e             500
```

I need the output as ,

```
Name          salary 
-----------------------
a             100
b             200
d             200
e             500-----------------till here it has to come in ascending order ignoring  'c'
c             300
c             400
c             600
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query and modify it accordingly

```
select name,salary,(select count(name) from table_name where name=a.name) count_nm from table_name a order by count_nm,salary;
```

Hope this helps!